# How to add empty row to the DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need to allow the user to add the information that is directly in the DataGrid but put the "CanUserAddRows" property does not work, only appears as follows:

[image]

This is my DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtgPersons" Grid.Row="3" CanUserAddRows="True">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="N°" Width="*" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Carrer" Width="*" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Group" Width="*" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Width="*" />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

**EDIT**

This is the new Grid code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtgPerson" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding lstPerson}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="N°" Width="*" Binding="{Binding No}" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Carrer" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Carrer}" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Group" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Group}" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Age}" />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And this is my code behind:
My ObservableCollection:

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> lstPerson { get; set; }
```

My MainWindow

```
public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     DataContext = this;
     lstPerson = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
}
```

My Person class

```
public class Person
{
    public int No { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Carrer { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Change you grid xaml

```
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GridCollection}" 
             CanUserAddRows="True" 
             AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="N°" Binding="{Binding Number}" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Carrer" Binding="{Binding Career}" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Group" Binding="{Binding Group}" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}" Width="*" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

2) Define your collection in ViewModel or CodeBehind

```
public ObservableCollection<gridDataModel> GridCollection { get; set; }
```

3) Init collection before use

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    GridCollection = new ObservableCollection<gridDataModel>();
}
```

4) After all you will get this, you can add items in grid via GUI and they will store in collection[image: result]

Comment: It works well but I still can add rows. When loading the form, it appears a row and I can insert data, but, pressing enter, send me this error:
**An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' in PresentationFramework.dll
Note: The bidirectional link requires Path or XPath.**
Thanks for your time, @galakt

Comment: @Richard How looks you data model? Because in my solution enter and tab work right

Comment: @Richard Yeah, but you didnt post your `Person`

Comment: @Richard Looks fine =\

Comment: I do not understand what happens :(
I very much appreciate your time.

Comment: thanks for this answer. But what is the use of "DataContext = this" line?

Comment: @maamaa In this case it is to bind Visualpart(View) and Codebehind(ViewModel). If delete this line, View will not understand where looking for GridCollection

Comment: Just adding to this if you are using this solution and have a custom object, your custom object needs a parameterless constructor

Answer (score -1):

You must define ItemsSource.

In your code behind:

```
List<YourObj> list = new List<YourObj>();
dtgPersons.ItemsSource = list;
```

Comment: I tried but did not work, I added some empty objects but can not edit on the cells created.