# WPF - C# users can't add rows to DataGridView even with CanUserAddRows="True"

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I am creating a program that allows users to access an sql database to view it's data and add items to tables as needed.

My problem is CanUserAddRows="True" is not adding a blank row to the bottom of the DataGridView like you see in the WinForms version.

This is my DataGridView

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,62,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="240" Width="487" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Width="40" Binding="{Binding NumProduit}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Produit" Width="*" Binding="{Binding NomProduit}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Width="36" Binding="{Binding NumType}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantite Actuelle" Width="105" Binding="{Binding QuantiteActuelle}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Seuil Minimum" Width="90" Binding="{Binding SeuilMinimum}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And here are my classes responsible of transfering the data from the SQL Database to my program

class ProduitGerer:

```
class ProduitGerer
{
    //Objet ProduitDAO
    private ProduitDAO produitdao = new ProduitDAO();

    public ProduitGerer()
    {

    }
    public List<ProduitVO> getListeProduit()
    {
        // Création de la liste d'objet Produit.
        List<ProduitVO> listProduitVO = new List<ProduitVO>();

        // Création de la liste selon les critères de requêtesSQL et des conditionsSQL.
        listProduitVO = this.produitdao.getListeProduit();

        return listProduitVO;
    }
}
```

class ProduitDAO:

```
class ProduitDAO
{
    public List<ProduitVO> getListeProduit()
    {
        List<ProduitVO> listeProduitVO = new List<ProduitVO>();
        // Ouverture de la connection et interrogation de la table Produit.
        string dp = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        string cnStr = "Data Source=(local)\\MSSQLSERVER2008;Initial Catalog=ProjetSession;Integrated Security=True";
        //Obtenir le «factory provider»
        DbProviderFactory df = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(dp);
        //Obtenir l'objet de connexion
        using (DbConnection cn = df.CreateConnection())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("L'objet de connexion est: {0}", cn.GetType().Name);
            cn.ConnectionString = cnStr;
            cn.Open();
            //Créer une commande
            DbCommand cmd = df.CreateCommand();
            Console.WriteLine("L'objet de commande est: {0}", cmd.GetType().Name);
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT *  FROM [ProjetSession].[dbo].[tblProduit]";
            using (DbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // Lecture de tous les résultats.
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    ProduitVO nouveauProduit = new ProduitVO();

                    nouveauProduit.NumProduit = int.Parse(dr["NumProduit"].ToString());
                    nouveauProduit.NomProduit = dr["NomProduit"].ToString();
                    nouveauProduit.Description = dr["Description"].ToString();
                    nouveauProduit.NumType = int.Parse(dr["NumType"].ToString());
                    nouveauProduit.QuantiteActuelle = int.Parse(dr["QuantiteActuelle"].ToString());
                    nouveauProduit.SeuilMinimum = int.Parse(dr["SeuilMinimum"].ToString());
                    listeProduitVO.Add(nouveauProduit);
                }
            }
        }
        return listeProduitVO;
    }
}
```

class ProduitVO:

```
class ProduitVO
{

    // Variables de stockage
    private int numProduit;
    private string nomProduit;
    private string description;
    private int numType;
    private int quantiteActuelle;
    private int seuilMinimum;

    public ProduitVO()
    {

    }

    public int NumProduit
    {
        get { return numProduit; }
        set { numProduit = value; }
    }

    public string NomProduit
    {
        get { return nomProduit; }
        set { nomProduit = value; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set { description = value; }
    }

    public int NumType
    {
        get { return numType; }
        set { numType = value; }
    }

    public int QuantiteActuelle
    {
        get { return quantiteActuelle; }
        set { quantiteActuelle = value; }
    }

    public int SeuilMinimum
    {
        get { return seuilMinimum; }
        set { seuilMinimum = value; }
    }
}
```

And finally I create an instance of ProduitGerer in my main class:

```
private ProduitGerer produit = new ProduitGerer();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Every solution I've seen on this site is using an ObservableCollection to store their data but I was not taught using that. So any solution using this method would be appreciated.

Comment: where is `ItemsSource`?

Comment: So I guess you've seen this solution then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36788039/5186384. Why don't you want to bind your `ProduitGerer` class and have a public property `GetListeProduit` that returns an `ObservableList<ProduitVO> `